# How do I send more data than ESP32 has ram through SPI

Tags: c++, esp32

I am using an S1V30120 dectalk text synthesis IC and on starting the chip I must send it its firmware. The problem is the firmware is 32kb which is larger than the ram on the esp32, I put the firmware on an EEPROM but I don't know how I would "stream" the data off the EEPROM over SPI to the slave.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the firmware into RAM before sending it? Is the firmware stored on a fixed address in the memory map? Then use a pointer to that address as the "buffer" to send.

Comment: Additionally you could take a look at DMA. Using this allow to copy data from one interface to the other with minimal cpu interaction.

Comment: Oh wow thanks guys. I'm a complete novice when it comes to the idf but I for some reason figured I needed to have the data in ram before sending through spi to be stored in ram. The eeprom is a seperate ic if that makes any difference but I'll look into the esp32s dma.

Comment: Assuming it is a SPI EEPROM chances are that you just need to add the "programming commands" either to the bitstream sequence stored on the EEPROM or "manually" send them at the beginning of the transmission and then simply turn on the DMA to shovel the data from one SPI to the other SPI.

Comment: The ESP32 has 520KB of internal SRAM. Even with caching, OS and libraries, there should be plenty of ram. I agree with the previous comments, but the storage is there.